# install ros on OSX10.8 failed

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosdep, osx, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after typing

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

it occur

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
> to system dependencies:
> smach_ros: Missing resource roslaunch
> ROS path [0]=/Users/pb/src
> roslisp: Missing resource std_srvs
> ROS path [0]=/Users/pb/src

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110416/install-ros-on-osx10.8-failed/) by [pbking](https://answers.ros.org/users/9916/pbking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-17**:
How did populate your workspace with packages?

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-14**:
I have the same problem! Is this issue solved yet?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-14**:
It seems os, as the answer by tfoote is marked as accepted. Maybe you want to open a new question giving some more information about your specific issue (in particular tell us what you did before calling rosdep, i.e. how did you populate your workspace with packages).

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-15**:
I have created a new question. Kindly look through it :
http://answers.ros.org/question/153156/rosdep-error-while-i-try-to-install-ros-on-os-x-108/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you are missing packages from your workspace. If you are missing dependencies rosdep will try to install them as system dependencies. However if there are not rules for the packages as system dependencies they will fail to resolve.

In particular I would make sure you have roslaunch in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0